# Subscript out of range with copy a range in one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, range, subscript, out

I have a range of data in a workbook that I would like to copy to the active workbook.  The code looks simple, but I am getting a subscript out of range error when I run the code.  What am I doing wrong?

Source = "C:\Data\Demographics.xlsx"
Destination = "C:\Data\Demographic_Import_2022_04_21.xlsm"

```
Workbooks(Source).Worksheets("Demographics").Range("B10:j39").Copy _
Workbooks(Destination).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")
```

Comment: If you want to use the workbook name as index into the `Workbooks`-collection, you need to use the workbook name without path.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Can you break it down for me?

Comment: `Source = "Demographics.xlsx"`

Comment: That is still not working for me.  If I use your code, how does it know where the source file is located.  Below is the code with the actual paths.

Comment: the argument for `Workbooks` is the file name only, not the full path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Open Workbooks

- You need to use `Workbooks.Open` to be able to use the complete path. This will work whether the files are open or not.
- Only when the workbooks are already open, you can use `Workbooks("Demographics.xlsx")` and `Workbooks("Demographic_Import_2022_04_21.xlsm")` without the paths.
- Also consider using `ThisWorkbook` for the workbook containing this code (no need to specify its name).

```vb
Sub OpenWorkbooks()
    
    ' Using constants and variables
    
    ' Source
    Const sPath As String = "C:\Data\Demographics.xlsx"
    Const sName As String = "Demographics"
    Const sRangeAddress As String = "B10:J39"
    ' Destination
    Const dPath As String = "C:\Data\Demographic_Import_2022_04_21.xlsm"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "B10"
 
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sRangeAddress)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dPath)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = sws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)

    ' Copy.
    srg.Copy dfCell
 
    ' or using constants, no variables (not recommended):
    'Workbooks.Open(sPath).Worksheets(sName).Range(sRangeAddress).Copy _
        Workbooks.Open(dPath).Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress)

    ' or using no constants, no variables (not recommended):
    'Workbooks.Open("C:\Data\Demographics.xlsx").Worksheets("Demographics").Range("B10:J39").Copy _
        Workbooks.Open("C:\Data\Demographic_Import_2022_04_21.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")

End Sub
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one follow-up question.  The source range always begins in Column B, but not always on the same row.  Likewise the right column is not always column J.  How can account for a dynamic range in the source file?  The source file is generated by an automated process and I have no control over its formatting.

Comment: There is too little information. Best ask another question and describe in more detail what needs to be done i.e. explain the logic of how the range is determined.